# Using a Single Supply OpAmp in inverting mode

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is it possible to use a single supply op amp in inverting mode by supplying it with GND -> Vcc?

EDIT: The input signal would never go negative.

Comment: What is "supplying it with GND -> Vcc" supposed to mean?

Comment: I understand your question. By Biasing a rail to rail OA with 0 differential input at Vcc output, then the gain must stay with the linear  CM input to successfully achieve an inverting  transfer function using a suitable offset and Vref  to Vin+ input. Define these parameters with your transfer function.

Comment: are you saying you want to connect 0V to the opamp positive rail? Please state what connects to the positive rail and negative rail of the opamp.

Answer (score 2):

An opamp can only generate output voltages within the range of its power rails.

If you supply the +ve and -ve power rails of an opamp with 5V and 0V (ground) respectively, you limit the linear range of the opamp output to 0V to 5V (± the rail offset of the particular opamp you're using). This means that any output voltage created by the opamp *must* be within 0-5V, otherwise you will hit the saturation range and "clip" your input signal.

In an inverting configuration, this means that if your input voltage is positive, you will *always* be in the saturation range, because any positive input voltage will attempt to create a negative output voltage, but your linear range is only 0-5V, so you saturate the opamp and get 0V out.

As you mention that "the input signal would never go negative", your proposed circuit would not work: your output would always be 0V because you would always be within the negative saturation range of the opamp, regardless of its gain.

As a side note, I should mention that the use of the terms "GND" and "Vcc" in relation to opamp supplies is largely erroneous, since the more appropriate terms are positive and negative rails (+ve and -ve). Voltage is a relative measurement, so tying the +ve pin to your circuit ground (0V) and the -ve pin to a -10V supply is absolutely acceptable, assuming you want to generate output voltages between 0V and -10V.

Comment: "In an inverting configuration, this means that if your input voltage is positive, you will always be in the saturation range, because any positive input voltage will attempt to create a negative output voltage, but your linear range is only 0-5V, so you saturate the opamp and get 0V out." this is not true.